# Add an application to notification tray in GNOME

Tags: application-development, system-tray, gnome-shell

I am developing a Linux application and I want an icon for the application to show up in the **notification tray** which is at **bottom-left** in **GNOME.**

Image of notification tray in GNOME:

[image: screenshot showing small notification tray bottom left of screen]

How can I show my application in the notification tray?

Comment: Just an info: this tray (known as legacy tray) is removed from the latest version of GNOME (v3.26).

Comment: How is this voted off-topic ? *Software development for Ubuntu and on Ubuntu is on topic* !

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy using the Ubuntu platform is. This is just the generic GNOME APIs

Comment: @muru  still considered software development on Ubuntu. Has what's off-topic changed ?  Doesn't GNOME that ships with Ubuntu  also use generic APIs ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy so what? Is the entire glibc interface now on topic here as well? GCC ships on Ubuntu, so how about generic C programming as well?

Comment: @muru that's a stretch, but I'm not gonna continue this discussion. I see AskUbuntu has really changed and doesn't seem like in the good direction

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy no it hasn't. Of course this is on topic. It is obviously a question about developing on Ubuntu and those have always been on topic.